# Two databases' columns reference as foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 databases A and B

In A there is a table, one of its columns is a column entry for elements in a table of B (id_A=id_B). While creating B, how should I reference A's table's column as a foreign key? Or I just need to ignore and once coding I will reference A's table as "A.Table" for example. I do this in mysql 5.3. Thank you.

**[UPDATE]**

I mean while I do something like this

```
CREATE DATABASE B;

USE B;

CREATE TBLE BT(id int primary key,
               _id int foreign key(_id) references A.TableX(_id));
```

Is this a correct command ?

Comment: Can you show the table structure and clarify your question? It is very hard to follow.

Comment: MySQL 5.3 ? Where did you get such a version?

Comment: Isn't there a 5.3 version of mysql ? I think there is.

Comment: The only (relative) i know with this number is MariaDB 5.3

Comment: And why do you also have [oracle] and [informix] tags? Please remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct - with some modifications:

```
CREATE TABLE B.tableB
( id int
, _id int 
, primary key (id)
, foreign key (_id)            --- the FK should not be declared inline in MySQL
    references A.TableX(_id)   --- (_id) should be the the PK of tableX in db A
) ;
```